# Wiring a ballast

Tags: wiring

Question my situation is much like Harper's With a 2 lamp ballast wiring to a single lamp on one end of the lampholder. I have a red and white wire - the red wire to the starter and the white wire connects to a neutral bus. So my question is if I connect the lamp per diagram, 2 blues and 2 reds, then where does that leave the white wire that is connected to the lamp holder? I'll be splicing the ballast wires into the existing so does one of these wires be it blue or red become a neutral ? Then what do I do with the white neutral coming from the ballast? I intend to connect the black wire from the ballast to the push button switch. What I'm working on is an old 1968 Frigidaire flair custom oven. I think I got it - the white wire from ballast connects to neutral bus the white wire on lamp holder becomes whichever color I wire to that side. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Most all ballasts I have wired use white or gray for neutral and black for the hot. The lamps are where the red(s) and blue(s) oranges, yellows etc are connected. The existing wires or connections to the lamp holders may need to be removed to wire this new ballast correctly.